# Lodash Merge objects and KEEP the duplicates

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to merge few objects into a single object, but **DO NOT remove the duplicates**. I've tried to use lodash.merge(), but it is replacing the duplicates. Also same issue with assign, but assign is doing shallow copy only and also replacing the duplicates.

```
_.merge({}, 
  { a: {
    large: {
      url: '1'
    }
  }}, 
  { b: {
    large: {
      url: '2'
    }
  }}, 
  { c: {
    large: {
      url: '3'
    }
  }}, 
  {a: {
    large: {
      url: '4'
    }
  }});
```

Result is

```
{
    "a": {
        "large": {
            "url": "4"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "large": {
            "url": "2"
        }
    },
    "c": {
        "large": {
            "url": "3"
        }
    }
}
```

But i need

```
{
     "a": {
         "large": {
             "url": "1"
          }
      },
      "b": {
          "large": {
             "url": "2"
          }
      },
      "c": {
          "large": {
              "url": "3"
          }
       },
      "a": {
          "large": {
               "url": "4"
          }
      },
    }
```

Please, help!

How can i keep the duplicates? Thanks!

Comment: cannot have 2 keys with same name

Comment: *"But i need"* You can't do that, you can't have two properties with the name `a`. Perhaps you want an array.

Comment: Is it possible to do with mergeWith? For example rename the duplicated key?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) to customize how the merge happens. In your case I'd suggest creating an array for any duplicate objects.

To do this, we'd create a `mergeCustomizer()` function that will output an array if we get duplicates.

```js
function mergeCustomizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (objValue) {
    return  [objValue].flat().concat(srcValue);
  }
  return srcValue 
}

let merged = _.mergeWith({}, 
  { a: {
    large: {
      url: '1'
    }
  }}, 
  { b: {
    large: {
      url: '2'
    }
  }}, 
  { c: {
    large: {
      url: '3'
    }
  }}, 
  {a: {
    large: {
      url: '4'
    }
  }}, mergeCustomizer);
  
console.log('Merged:',merged)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```